# Django - Model's Primary Key Not Functioning As Expected

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a to-do website with Django. I use modals so users can create events. The event is a button, so when the user clicks on it, it displays a modal with the event info. I do this by passing a primary key to the url. However, nothing is displayed.

[image]

The primary key also isn't functioning when I manually go to the /view/(event-pk). I think it has something to do with `data-id="{% url 'view-event' event.pk %}"`, but everything looks fine. I'm fairly new to Django, so I apologize if it's a simple question.

Html that displays the events div:

```
<div class="col-md-6 inline mb-4">  
  <h3 class="ml-1">Events:</h3> 
    <div class="events-content-section ml-2">
    {% for event in events %}  
    <div class="mb-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">  
    <button type="button" class="view-event btn btn-light" style="width: 100%;" data-id="{% url 'view-event' event.pk %}">
      <span>
        <h4 style="float: left;">{{ event.title|truncatechars:29 }}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="update-event btn btn-sm btn-info ml-1" data-id="{% url 'update-event' event.pk %}" style="float: right;">
          <span class="fas fa-edit"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="delete-event btn btn-sm btn-danger mr-2 ml-2" data-id="{% url 'delete-event' event.pk %}" style="float: right;">
          <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
        </button>   
      </span>
    </button> 
  </div>
  {% endfor %}  
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript for the modal button (if it even matters):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".create-event").modalForm({
        formURL: "{% url 'new-event' %}"
    });
});
```

HTML for the view:

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load static %}
{% bootstrap_css %}   
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/main.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{ event.title }}</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="">
            Description:
            {{ event.description }}
        </div> 
        <div class="">
            Start Time:
            {{ event.start_time }}
        </div>
        <div class="">
            End Time:
            {{ event.end_time }}
        </div>
        <div class="">
            Remind Time:
            {{ event.remind_time }}
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='app-home'),
    path('new_event/', EventCreateView.as_view(), name='new-event'),
    path('update/<int:pk>/', EventUpdateView.as_view(), name='update-event'),
    path('view/<int:pk>/', EventReadView.as_view(), name='view-event'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', EventDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete-event'),
    path('calendar/', calendar_view, name='calendar'),
]
```

Views.py

```
class EventReadView(BSModalReadView):
    model = ToDoItem
    template_name = 'main/todoitem_view.html'
```

I want the event to get passed through by the data-id and displayed on the view, so description, start time, etc. is filled out.

As for the js that uses the data-id, I use [django bootstrap modal forms](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/), so everything is taken care of by the installed app.

Comment: You haven't shown any of the relevant information here to make it possible to answer the question. Where is the JS that uses that `data-id` to display the modal? Where is the urls.py? Where is the view that populates the template? What is it actually supposed to look like?

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: Your model is ToDoItem, so you need to use `todoitem`, not `event`, in the template.